# magento get all options of an attribute that are associated to one product or more

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I would like to get all options (active options maybe) of an attribute that are associated to one product or more

exemple :

I have a color attribute with three dropdown options (red, blue, black).

also i have 2 products with color red, 2 with color blue and 0 products black.

how can i get list of active attribute options (in this case : red and blue) ?

Comment: use configurable product. which version of magento you are using

Comment: Hey @Shakir, i'm using Magento ver. 1.14.2.1